# How to implement ezypay in my wordpress with integrate in woocoomerce

Tags: wordpress

**Please any one can tell me how to implement it. this is the requirement for me.in advanced Thank You very much**

```
function GetCustomerDetails() {
    $url = 'https://api.ezypay.com/api/v1/customers/11111111-1111-1111-1111-1111';

$ch = curl_init($url);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");                                                                                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "aZj1zkAivrnZiiWpiM71O3hBUAAN6S:a");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
'Content-Type: application/json',  
'Accept: application/json', 
'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data))  
);
```